# I am trying to Make a Quiz app for training in Flutter and Dart, and would appreciate assistance in getting the following error cleared

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting two errors one in Quiz.dart and another in Main.dart.

In main.dart I am getting an error on **answerQuestion: _answerQuestion**,

**Error: [The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.]**

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './quiz.dart';
import './result.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite Color?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Red', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'White', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Black', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'Green', 'score': 1},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Dog', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Cat', 'score': 7},
        {'text': 'Monkey', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Tiger', 'score': 2},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite Number',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Raman', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Krishnan', 'score': 7},
        {'text': 'Balan', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Gopi', 'score': 2},
      ],
    },
  ];
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  var _totalScore = 0;

  void _answerQuestion(int score) {
    _totalScore += score;
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My First App'),
      ),
      body: _questionIndex < _questions.length
          ? Quiz(
              answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
              questionIndex: _questionIndex,
              questions: _questions,
            )
          : Result(_totalScore),
    ));
  }
}
```

in quiz.dart I am getting an error on **answerQuestion(answer['score'])**,

**Error:Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra arguments.**

**Quiz.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './answer.dart';
import './question.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  // final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final VoidCallback answerQuestion;

  Quiz({
    required this.questions,
    required this.answerQuestion,
    required this.questionIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'],
        ),
        // ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text']);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried my best to understand the error, your assistance is highly appreciated, thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `void _answerQuestion` function expects an `int` parameter value but the class `Quiz` declares `final VoidCallback answerQuestion` and functions of the type [`VoidCallback`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/VoidCallback.html) doesn't expects any kind of parameter.

That is why you are getting **The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'** error message.
You can define your own type using `typedef` keyword or use [`ValueSetter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueSetter.html) from flutter foundation instead `VoidCallback`.

```
typedef MyOwnFunction = void Function(int score);
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
    //...
    final MyOwnFunction answerQuestion;
    //...
}
```

Or just replace `VoidCallback answerQuestion` by `ValueSetter<int> answerQuestion` in `Quiz` class.

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed the VoidCallback answerQuestion to Function answerQuestion & the issue got resolved. Actually I had an error previously when I declared it as function that is why I had changed it to VoidCallback. Still a beginner so has to fall a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem but I corrected it.
You should change the
`final VoidCallback answerQuestion;`
as     `final Function  answerQuestion;`

It works

Answer (score 0):

`VoidCallback` is a `void Function()` prototype but you pass to `answerQuestion` the `void Function(int)`. Use, for example, `ValueSetter<int>`.

In regarding to second error check how you pass parameters to `Answer` constructor. I think you have named parameters (they are wrapped with curved parenthesis) but you pass them as positional.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, just change:

- `final VoidCallback answerQuestion;`
  to
- `final Function answerQuestion;`
  It worked for me like a charm

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue for me i had:

```
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> fragen;
  final int frageIndex;
  final Function() antwortFrage;
```

the Solution was to remove the bracers from:

```
final Function antwortFrage;
```